# Oracle 1.8 CachedRowSet.populate error where select systimestamp from dual

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, timestamp, cachedrowset

I have a simple question... Why this code below is not working?

- JDK version: 1.8.0_92
- Oracle DB version: 11.2.0.1.0
- Oracle JDBC driver: ojdbc6.jar  ---> I could not find this java code source :(

  ```
  String SQL = "select systimestamp from dual";

  Statement statement = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;
  try {
      statement = getConnection(name).createStatement();
      if (statement != null) {
          rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
      }

      // Need to use a CachedRowSet that caches its rows in memory, which
      // makes it possible to operate without always being connected to
      // its data source
      CachedRowSet rowset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
      rowset.populate(rs);
      return rowset;
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
      throw new DatabaseException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
  } finally {
      safeCloseResultSet(rs);
      safeCloseStatement(statement);
  }
  ```

The stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL type for column
at javax.sql.rowset.RowSetMetaDataImpl.checkColType(RowSetMetaDataImpl.java:114)
at javax.sql.rowset.RowSetMetaDataImpl.setColumnType(RowSetMetaDataImpl.java:459)
at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.initMetaData(CachedRowSetImpl.java:761)
at com.sun.rowset.CachedRowSetImpl.populate(CachedRowSetImpl.java:639)
```

The line "**rowset.populate(rs);**" throws a "j**ava.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL type for column**"

The error occurs when I try to execute the query:

```
select systimestamp from dual
```

But if I use the code below instead of "**rowset.populate(rs);**", it works:

```
rs.getTimestamp(1)
```

And if I try to execute the query below, **everything** works well:

```
select sysdate from dual
```

So, how can I use the **rowset.populate(rs)** to get the **syscurrenttimestamp**?

I start to think that it is a bug of oracle's jdbc implementation...

Sorry about my bad english :)

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, sorry. I'd just ask - if I may - how precise does this value have to be? SYSDATE contains up to seconds; SYSTIMESTAMP additionally includes fractional seconds with timezone. I'm just hoping that SYSDATE *might* be enough.

Comment: Could be a bug in the driver. Maybe you should try a newest version of the driver ? Review the README file on drivers download page: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/default-2280470.html, for example it could be this bug: `11670695    RESULTSET.GETTIMESTAMP() RETURNS WRONG TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
        Possible wrong timestamp with TIMESTAMPLTZ if db and
        session timezone are equal.`

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot! Thanks for your attention! The problem with SYSDATE is that the time information hh:mm:ss depends of how the Oracle NLS_DATE_FORMAT is configured, and in my case, I can not change it. Anyway I have business rules that require the milliseconds information.

Comment: Hi @krokodilko! Yes! I upgraded the JDBC driver with the [Oracle Database 12c Release 2  (12.2.0.1) drivers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html) (I think that it is the most younger), but the problem still persists.

Comment: I ended up solving the problem with a palliative solution. Instead of performing the query to return a TIMESTAMP, I made it to return a STRING 
(`SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.SSXFF TZR') FROM DUAL`). And then I had to do a parse to TIMESTAMP. I know that it's ugly, but is just until we find a correct solution. 
I still have hope that someone will help us with this matter.

Comment: @Jefferson please post this comment as the answer (answer your own question), this is a smart and very good  workaround, it can be usefull to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @krokodilko suggests, I will post here my comment as an answer:

I ended up solving the problem with a palliative solution. Instead of performing the query to return a TIMESTAMP, I made it to return a STRING:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.SSXFF TZR') FROM DUAL
```

And then I had to do a parse to TIMESTAMP. I know that it's ugly, but is just until we find a correct solution. I still have hope that someone will help us with this matter.